# Machine restarts without warning when installing VSTO 2010 v. 10.0.40303

Tags: vsto, installshield

I'm trying to accomodate our installation software to include VSTO 2010 Runtime (v. 10.0.40303) as a pre-requisite prior to installing our software. What happens when we try to install our software on client machines (Win7 and Win8) is that the machine upon completing installation of the VSTO 2010 Runtime reboots without any warning.

Apparently, this is because of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 X64 Redistributable (v.10.0.40219) which is bundled along with the VSTO 2010 runtime installer. It (C++ redistributable) attempts to replace files which are currently locked by the explorer.exe process which forces the reboot?

At the moment I have no idea how to resolve this, so any suggestions are more than welcome.

The messages that I take note off in the log file of the VSTO installation are below:

```
Windows Installer requires a system restart. 
Product Name: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219 
Product Version: 10.0.40219. Product Language: 0. 
Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. 
Type of System Restart: 2. Reason for Restart: 1.
```

This appears at the bottom of the log file for installing the VSTO 2010 Runtime.

```
MSI (c) (C4:80) [21:42:34:552]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. 
If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
```

I have no idea which counter we're decrementing? Should I care or try to manipulate with it to prevent restart?

From what I'm able to tell, it's the (among others) files ATL100.DLL, MSVCP100.dll which are locked by the explorer.exe process and the replacement of those causing the reboot.

Come to think of it, this issue didn't occur on machines which DIDN'T need to have a language pack installed. The native language of the Win7 and Win8 machines is Danish. Could this be caused by language packs instead of the C++ Redistributables?

The way I constructed my pre-requisite was to take the existing pre-requisite for installing the VSTO 2010 runtime supplied with InstallShield 2013 and then just modify the version number used to check in the registry and the redistributable that the pre-requisite should install.

The commandline in InstallShield for installing the redistributable (vstor40_redist.exe) is:

```
/q:a /c:"install /q /l"
```

How do I configure my pre-requisite to at least notify the user that a restart is imminent, preferably defer it until the end of the installation?
What should I look for in the log files?

Comment: I've tried to go through the log files again. The language pack doesn't seem to indicate any need for a restart. Only the VC_Red_x64\vc_red.msi package (i.e. C++ 2010 redistributable) appears to require this. How do I postpone or suppress this?

Comment: You could also have a look in the Windows Event Viewer, to see if any details about the requested restart are found there. In what regards controlling restarts, you could make an ideea about how to control it from this article (which you can apply to any MSI builder tool): http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-reboot-after-install.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the /norestart parameter to the msi